# Why does it show same random number when i run it as a script? #PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Hello guys when i run this script it prints the same number twice:

```
$RandomNumber = Get-Random
$RandomNumber
$RandomNumber
```

But when I type `Get-Random` command in console and do it again it gives different numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic of having `variables` in any programming language or scripting language. If you want to save a value for later use, you assign the value to a `variable`.

In this case your `$RandomNumber` is the variable. You are already assigning the value of `Get-Random` cmdlet to `$RandomNumber` variable. Hence, every time you try to get the value of `$RandomNumber` variable, you will be getting the value which PoSh had assigned to it in the first case
If you want to generate random number every single time, only run the `Get-Random` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning the `Get-Random` value to `$RandomNumber`.
I think this is what you need to do

```
$RandomNumber = Get-Random
$RandomNumber
$RandomNumber = Get-Random
$RandomNumber
```

Or simply you can type

```
Get-Random
Get-Random
```

Both will give the different number.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the same thing in the script and at the console.

The script you showed invokes Get-Random once, saving the value.  It then invokes the saved value twice.  Of course it will give the same value both times.  $randomnumber is just a variable.

If you do the same thing at the console, you will get the same result.

If, on the other hand, you invoke Get-Random twice, you will not get the same number twice in a row.  You will get the first two numbers in some sequence of random numbers.  See the examples in get-help get-random -ex

Try writing and running a script that simply invokes Get-Random twice.  You will see that the script gives two different numbers.